# How to simulate a vibration sensor network in contiki cooja?

Tags: simulation, contiki

I am very new to contiki cooja.I have to simulate a vibration sensor network using ccoja.Is it possible?My aim is to simulate a vibration sensor network which gives indication when the vibration is above a particular threshold.How can i do this in ccoja?

Comment: What's "vibration sensor network"? What have you tried so far (code, ideas)? Don't expect SO will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cooja only emulate specific board. So you can't test your vibration sensor.
But you can use a specific cooja board for the radio, and send random data to simulate sensor data.